# jsp caching and back button

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee

i have problem with history.go(-1) and jsp page .

i have jsp page that is make ajax call , after the call i want to go back to the previous page by using history.go(-1)  , it's not work in IE , but it's work fine with firefox .

in IE it's show me this :

Webpage has expired

Most likely cause:
The local copy of this webpage is out of date, and the website requires that you download it again

is this problem from the caching  , so how i enable the caching ? so the back will work fine ?

please help me :(

thank you ,

Comment: Are you talking about plain jsp or jsf?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use response.sendRedirect("previousPag.jsp") to go to the previous page, no need to use javascript functions history.go(-1). This may be over head for server side code, but since you are making an AJAX call may be cache is loaded with that AJAX call which deletes your previous cache pointed to the JSP Page in IE.